# How Do I Find My Current Desktop Theme in Kubuntu 15.10?

Tags: kubuntu, themes, kde, settings, plasma

I have been using Kubuntu 15.10 for about 6 months, and have been using previous versions for over 3 years. I customized my desktop theme, icons, etc. to suit me, however, recently, I downloaded more desktop themes, and want to try them only. But I am not sure how to get back to my present theme, if I do not like them. My questions are:

- Why there is no info in system settings like "Current desktop theme?" Relating to this, how do I find my current desktop theme?
- why there is no button for saving the present settings as 'save as a new desktop theme' or something like that
- How to save my present desktop theme to a name that I can see in the list and get back if needed?

Here is some additional information. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ip0d.png) is a list of my current themes, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKko0.png) are the details of my customizations. I would appreicate any help is attempting to solve this. Thanks

Comment: Not sure who Rutkowski is, but I think that's the author of the *theme*, not the software you're using to set the theme. :) If you want to make a feature request, see https://userbase.kde.org/Asking_Questions#Reporting_KDE_Bugs

Comment: To be clear, did you install “Kubuntu” or did you install Ubuntu and then KDE?

Comment: @It's Willem -  I installed Kubuntu directly; [not the other way like Ubuntu+KDE] as it includes KDE.  - Thanks

Comment: @muru - I thought he is the author of  the theme.  I believe you actually provided me the answer.  My current theme looks like KArc.  But I did a lot of customization, added so many bells and whistles.  Did not keep track of what I did over the time, so want to save it first before I experiment.  - Thanks

Comment: Apparently the original theme is available here: https://github.com/zbeptz/KArc-theme

Comment: yes, I am aware of the source for original theme.  But I am looking for saving my current customized theme as a new one.  I mean, that should not involve any excessive programming etc.  I am not trained.

Comment: If you are "not trained", I suggest you stay with a LTS version of Kubuntu rather than a version which isn't supported after nine months. You are probably correct in assuming that excessive programming isn't needed. On other *buntu flavors, users can set up their own themes (copied over from the system and just renamed) in their own /home and hack away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**KDE plasma desktop themes**

Information of the KDE plasma themes can be found from the KDE TechBase: https://techbase.kde.org/Development/Tutorials/Plasma

and

The KDE UserBase has a link to 'Using Multiple Plasma Themes': https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/TweakingPlasma#Using_Multiple_Plasma_Themes

**Plasma 5 theme editor before the plasma 5.6**

The user can edit the plasma desktop theme from KDE system settings > Workspace Theme > Desktop Theme. In the Details tab there is an option make a cutomized/mixed plasma theme.

[image]

With the KF5 (plasma 5) the Customized plasma theme is saved to the ~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/.customized .

[image]

The user can rename/copy (at this MyNewTheme) the theme to the ~/.local/share/plasma/desktoptheme/MyNewTheme .

[image]

After the user edits the metadata.desktop file...

[image]

the plasma theme is available from the KDE System Settings. The current theme has blue 'halo' ( depends current color settings)

[image]

**Removal of the Theme Details KCM**

KDE review board - Remove Theme Details KCM: https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/126953/

KDE Bug report:  Bug 359127 - Desktop theme KCM 'details' and editing tab no longer present/functional - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359127

**Wishes - why there is no...**

The KDE Forums ( https://forum.kde.org )has a sub forum for the 'User-submitted ideas for KDE desktop and software - KDE Brainstorm': https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=83 . There is also an option to file a wish to the KDE bug tracking system: https://bugs.kde.org

Comment: Thanks a lot!  it worked for me.  I am now doing editing as I want and can keep different versions of desktop themes.  My working conditions are different, especially with available lighting; so really need different desktop themes ranging from light versions to darker ones.  Specifically thanks for the screens, they are helpful.  Enjoy your day!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Kubuntu 15.10 Install at the moment but you should be able to access the KDE theme manager by running kcontrol. Here is how:

> You can reach the Theme Manager by running KControl, KDE's Control Center.
>
> - Click on the K Menu and select Run Command (alternatively, you could also press Alt+F2).
> - In the Run Command dialog box, enter the text kcontrol and click on the Run button or press the Enter key.
> - The Theme Manager is under the Appearance group of the Control Center.

from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeKubuntu

You should find your current theme and other settings there

Comment: I tried your instructions.  No result.  There is no such command as KControl.  When I pressed Alt+F2 is taking me to 'Plasma Search - KDE Control Module, under that only 'Plasma Search' is there.  There is no item as 'Appearance'.  May be these instructions belong to Ubuntu [note that I am asking help on Kubuntu]? or may be these are meant for older versions distros.     Not sure how to figure this out.  May be I just do not go ahead with any experimentation.  I have only one laptop  now, which I use for work extensively.  Waiting on responses from others, to see how good it is to experiment.

Comment: Well, the link says kubuntu at the end. I hope you tried `kcontrol` all lower case, and not `KControl` as you've mentioned

Comment: @MariaFernanda, did you look at the link Harsh provided? It's pretty comprehensive. Unfortunately, it was last updated in 2012 and KDE is evolving pretty fast!

Comment: @DK Bose - Yes, I looked at, it is exhaustive.  But I quickly realized it might be out of date.  So did not attempt to.  Another lead is - kcontrol is not a command that is working my kubuntu 15.10.  When I tried in the terminal; it says 'not found' and got suggestions to use 'dcontrol, scontrol, ccontrol' and a few more.  I really did not want to be pain to all you guys, so kep quite.  Now trying the instructions provided by 'user26687'; will keep all you posted. - Thanks.